# Copy of NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I need to know that how can i make a copy of `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary` and change values of there.

Edit

I ned to know how to modify data of a NSDictionary. I got to know that

Copy data of `NSDictionary` to a `NSMutableDictionary`. and then modify data in `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: In Swift use the native `Dictionary` type with `var.`

Comment: This could have been easily looked up.  @vadian, that doesn't make a copy and he may need NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary for other things.

Comment: `Dictionary` is value type by default so it does make a copy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
let f : NSDictionary = NSDictionary() 
var g = f.mutableCopy()
```

Comment: Just note that this does not make copies of objects inside the dictionary, just  references

Answer (score 8):

You should initialize the NSMutableDictionary using it's dictionary initializer, here's a quick example in Playground

```
let myDict:NSDictionary = ["a":1,"b":2]

let myMutableDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: myDict)

myMutableDict["c"] = 3

myMutableDict["a"] // 1
myMutableDict["b"] // 2
myMutableDict["c"] // 3
```

Alternatively, you can declare a Swift dictionary as a var and mutate it whenever you want.

```
var swiftDictioanry : [String:AnyObject] = ["key":"value","key2":2]
```

The AnyObject value type mimics the behavior of an NSDictionary, if all types are known it can be declared like so:

```
var myNewSwiftDict : [String:String] = ["key":"value","nextKey":"nextValue"]
```